# combining two pandas dataframes as single json output

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine two pandas dataframes into a single JSON output.

The json output below is the result from this code - `df.to_json(orient = "split")`

```
{
  columns: [],
  index: [],
  data: [
    [
      "COMPANY ONE",
      "123 HAPPY PLACE",
      "GOTHAM CITY",
      "NJ",
      12345,
      "US",
      8675309,
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ],
    [.....]
  ]
 }
```

A little background, I get the data from a csv file, and usually I have to separate the file in two parts, one good and the other bad.  I've been using pandas for this process, which is great. So `df` contains the good data and say `dfbad` contains the bad data.

I used `df.to_json(orient = "split")` to output the good data, which I really like the structure of it. Now I want to do the same thing for the bad data, same structure, so something like this:

`[{good}, {bad}]`

I apologize in advance if the example above is not clear.

I tried to this:

`jsonify(good = df.to_json(orient = "split"), bad = dfbad.to_json(orient = "split"))`

But i know this is not going to work because the result for good and bad are turned into a string; which I don't want, I want to be able to have access to it.

```
data_dict = {}

data_dict['bad'] = dfbad.to_dict()
data_dict['good'] = df.to_dict()

return pd.json.dumps(data_dict)
```

This returns fine as a json, but not the structure I want, the way `.to_json(orient = "split")` does, unless I have to customize it.

Can anybody help with this issue?  or can pinpoint in another direction how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution, here is what I did:

```
good_json = df.to_json(orient="split")
bad_json = dfbad.to_json(orient="split")

return jsonify(bad = json.loads(bad_json), good = json.loads(good_json))
```

I added `json.loads`, you have to import it - `import json` - and it's now returning as a JSON output.  If you have other suggestions, please let me know.  I'm open to learn more about Pandas.

Comment: Could you not do `import pandas as pd` then  `pd.concat([df, dfbad]).to_dict(orient='split')`

Comment: @BobHaffner this works fine, I like that the code is very simple however, it doesn't put the structure I want. This line puts the `dfbad` at the bottom, but I want both dataframes to be in two parts, something like this `{ good:{...}, bad: {}}`.  Also, shouldn't be `.to_json()` instead of `.to_dict()`, I had an error when I used your line, I had to replace it w/ `.to_json()`.  I'm using it in a Flask app.